# How to set up uitextfield so what the user types has to meet specific criteria(ie. uppercase, number, etc.)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I'm trying to set up specific criteria the user must create in order to create a new account.  The criteria is as follows:

1. Password must start with a letter
2. At least 1 upper case letter
3. At least 1 lower case letter
4. At least 1 number
5. At least 1 Special Character
6. The password may not contain username

There was more criteria but these are the ones giving me the most problems.  Any help on any of them is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the problem with checking the password for all the constraints/criteria?

Comment: What exactly are you having an issue with?

Comment: I'm not sure how to set up RegEx efficiently in Swift 3

Comment: It helps if you show the code you have attempted. Other wise the question is to vague. Always try to include code and point to the area of issue.

Comment: Why do you assume using a regex is the best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method:

```
func validate(pass: String, userName: String) -> Bool {
    guard pass.characters.count > 0 else {return false }
    guard pass != userName else {return false }

    //Checks if the first character is a lowercase letter
    let firstIndex = pass.index(pass.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
    guard pass.substring(to: firstIndex).rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.lowercaseLetters) != nil else { return false }

    guard pass.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.uppercaseLetters) != nil else { return false }
    guard pass.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.lowercaseLetters) != nil else { return false }
    guard pass.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits) != nil else { return false }

    let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789")
    guard pass.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet.inverted) != nil else { return false }

    return true
}
```

Comment: This is really good, is there a way to check if the first character of the uitextfield is a lowercase letter?

Comment: @SwiftyJD See the updated code. I've checked it, works fine.

Comment: This works great! Thanks for your help

Comment: @SwiftyJD You're welcome. Happy coding ;)

Answer (score -1):

Create functions that loop through each character of the entered password and check to see if it is contained in a particular string. For the upper case letter,
loop through each character of the password, like this:

```
for c in password.characters {
    if "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".range(of:String(c)) != nil {
        return
    }
}
//if for loop is exited, alert user that their password is invalid.
```

Comment: I just tried this, I get an error " Cannot convert value of type 'String.CharacterView._Element' (aka 'Character') to expected argument type 'String'"

Comment: Sorry, try converting c to a string like this: String(c)